# Is this a mistake in my Computer Architecture book?

Tags: cpu-architecture

I'm working on my HW for computer architecture and I came across the following problem:

> A = 247
>   B = 237
>
> 1) Assume A and B are signed 8-bit integers stored in two's complement format.  Calculate A + B using saturating arithmetic.  The result should be written in decimal.  Show your work.
>   2) Assume A and B are signed 8 bit integers stored in two's compelemnt format.  Calculate A - B using saturating arithmetic.

Now, how are these even a valid questions?  I know what saturating arithmetic is, but how is it valid to say that A is 247 and B is 237 when they can't be represented by an 8-bit two's complement number?

I realize the point of saturated arithmetic is in the case of a overflow/underflow to set all the bits to the extreme value but it doesn't make sense to me to ask a series of questions (there are 3 more with this same problem) involving arithmetic of numbers that can't be represented in the format they specify.

Am I wrong here?

Comment: @Perpetualcoder, If you have nothing to add why bother commenting?  It is beyond the time of the day I can get in contact with my professor and I'm doing my homework ~now~.  If it was one problem I would skip it but seeing as there are many, I decided to ask SO if I was missing something.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only interpretation that makes sense is that the values given are the *unsigned* interpretation of the number in question; values greater than 127 are obviously out of range for an 8-bit signed twos-complement value. I agree that the question is poorly stated, however.

Comment: Yeah this is the only approach that makes sense to me.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know, but it *might* be asking: "Convert the decimal number 237 to an 8-bit integer. Now interpret those bits as an 8-bit 2's complement integer and add them".

Kinda like saying, in C:

```
char a = 237;
printf("%x %d\n",a, a);
```

Which compiles and gives you values that you would expect based on the 2's complement interpretation of the 8-bit value "237"

Answer (score 1):

Looks wrong to me.  8-bit signed two's complement integers can be between -128 and 127.  Any attempt to assign a constant 237 or 247 to an 8-bit signed two's complement variable should result in an error, depending on your language.

Comment: It works without error in C. As well it should - there should only be an error if overflow occurs, which is not the case here. "237" is simply translated to its bit-representation, which fits in 8 bits. No difference between that and assigning the byte to 0xED

Comment: @rasher: The standard would disagree about that. Converting unsinged to signed value where it does not fit in the underlying type is implementation specified on the result. But this is an architecture question. Not a question on what C would do.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem was "assume that A and B are stored in an 8 bit signed integer", then it would make sense. Storing A = 247 in a signed 8 bit integer yields a value of -9, storing B = 237 yields a value of -19. Otherwise, it doesn't make sense. A signed 8 bit integer cannot have a value of 247 or 237.